# Openbox mousebinds not recognizing remaps of Pointer_Button1 & Pointer_Button3

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, xmodmap

In openbox, when I press the left or right buttons from the mouse over the titlebar of a window, the later focuses, raises and unshades. The behavior is given by the following mousebinds from openbox *rc.xml* config file:

```
<mouse>
  <context name="Titlebar">
    <mousebind button="Left" action="Press">
      <action name="Focus"/>
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="Unshade"/>
    </mousebind>
    <mousebind button="Right" action="Press">
      <action name="Focus"/>
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="Unshade"/>
    </mousebind>
  </context>
<mouse>
```

Now I remap `AltGr+u` to left mouse button and `AltGr+o` to right mouse button:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  30 = u U u U Pointer_Button1 uparrow downarrow uparrow u U downarrow uparrow"
xmodmap -e "keycode  32 = o O o O Pointer_Button3 Oslash oslash Oslash o O oslash Oslash"
```

The remaps show to work within the window clients, by selecting items or text and opening menus.

Even so, the openbox mousebinds don't work with the remaps, that is, when pressing the `AltGr+u` or `AltGr+o` combination with the pointer placed over the titlebars, the windows do not focus/raise/unshade at all as they do when pressing the actual mouse buttons.

How to make the mousebinds work with these remaps?

Comment: If you have a numpad, consider enabling [Mouse keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys).

Comment: Yes I use mouse keys, but I don't want the alternating from right click and left click by pressing "/" and "-", so I'm trying to rebind the mouse buttons directly, for single keypress for right click or left click.

Comment: By the way I also remapped 5 from the numpad with mousekeys activated and the same happened, openbox mousebind don't work with these remaps either.